# Change bootstrap 3 panel type on hover in Angular js app

Tags: html, css, angularjs, twitter-bootstrap-3

In an Angular JS 1.3 app Using Bootstrap 3, how to change the panel type on mouse hover

```
    <div class="panel panel-default> to  <div class="panel panel-info>
```

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this

```
<div class="panel panel-default" 
     ng-class="{panel-info: hover}" 
     ng-mouseenter="hover = true"
     ng-mouseleave="hover = false">
</div>
```

Comment: try now, i have removed panel class in ng-class

Comment: That's clever, modifying the CSS class on hover instead of relying on the `:hover` CSS pseudo-class.

Answer (score 1):

You can achieve this with simple jquery for adding new class on mouser-Over and remove on Mouse-Out

```
$(".panel")
  .mouseover(function() {
    $(this).addClass('panel-info');
  })
  .mouseout(function() {
    $(this).removeClass('panel-info');
  });
```

> https://jsfiddle.net/ShirishDhotre/4khoydbe/